# JS run function with in multi dim object failing.. not sure if this is even posisble

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, i have an attribue on a html element: data-content='from:function:project101.login.check'

I want to be able to run the function which lies within project101.login.check.

But with the js i have written i am not sure how i could achieve this.

At the moment the js get to the string but then cannot run it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3M7hC/

The html

```
<a href="some href" data-loader data-content='from:function:project101.login.check' >target</a>
```

The JS

```
var project101 = {
    login: {
        check: function(){
            alert('function hit!');
        }
    }
}


$('*[data-loader]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        var contentParams = $(this).attr('data-content').split(':');
        console.log( contentParams );
        switch( contentParams[0] ){
            case 'from':
                switch( contentParams[1] ){
                    case 'function':

                        contentParams[2]();
                    break;

                }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, you can split the string on `.` and drill down the object until you get to the place you need.

```
function getObjFromPath(path, context){
    var obj = context || window,
        pathArray = path.split('.');

    for(var i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++){
        obj = obj[pathArray[i]];
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Then just call the function:

```
var func = getObjFromPath(contentParams[2]);
func();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SyFWh/

Answer (score 1):

You may use it like

```
eval(contentParams[2])();
```

as what you get in `contentParams[2]` is just a string, and not a function object. 
So `eval(..)` evaluates it to a `js` function, which *can* be eventually called.

Comment: ah ha! i finially have a use for eval.. however i read everywhere that eval is bad..

Comment: it's has tremendous potential, and with great power comes great responsibility. if you really need it, use it wisely. it's not evil, it is dangerous.

Comment: yes but then the function could be open to cross site attacks if not used correctly. Thank you very much though!